# Android Wearable - Loading Indicator

Tags: android, layout, loading, wear-os

I'm developing a android wear os application and would like to intergrate an loading animation. The bluetooth search animation is beautiful, see this:
https://files.fm/f/gh8nqczx5

Do I have to code this from scratch with a circle progessBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically use androidx.compose.material.CircularProgressIndicator

See https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/integration-tests/material-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/demos/ProgressIndicatorDemo.kt?q=CircularProgressIndicator

But it's material compose, not wear material which you should normally avoid.

If it doesn't look like you want you can google, there are lots of tutorials for this type of thing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZasJB95VBtM